# Bind TextBlock text to Resources

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

How can I bind a TextBlock Text to a string from Resources files? (My app is supposed to support many languages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a good example of localizing strings you'll use in XAML.

[How to: Make XAML Content Localized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)